# Building all dependencies in Maven

Tags: maven

I have a Ear, war and 2 jar projects in my eclipse.
I want to automatically build 2 jars, war and ear project, when i run the pom inside ear project.

I remember doing this in maven in the past. But i forgot since i lost touch working with Maven for few years now.

Someone please remind me of that..

I used dependency compile, but it is not building jar, when i build the ear directly.
Should i first run pom in jar? does it not build that jar automatically when i build ear?

Comment: What do you mean by "run the pom"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a multi module build that will build it all for you in the reactor. Read more about it e.g. http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-multi-vs-inherit

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should define tha `.jar` and `.war` projects as dependencies of your `.ear` project. It is also advisable to have a parent `pom`, where all the projects are defined as modules, including the `.ear` project.

In [this book](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-web-spring.html) you can find a well explained step-by-step setup of a maven multimodule project (with downloadable code).

There is also a great working example of an enterprise multimodule project in the [JBoss quickstart examples](https://github.com/jbossas/quickstart/tree/master/kitchensink-ear).

Comment: Thanks all.. I got it. The problem is the parent pom's artifact and children pom artifacts are not in sync. Hence the issue. I got it resolved and i am able to clean, install 13 projects at a single click. cool...